# Why does RotateTransform.Transform() return this Point?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a bounding box for a rotated Rectangle that I allow users to rotate by specifying the angle. To accomplish this, I assign the RenderTransform of the Rectangle to a RotateTransform and edit the Angle to accomplish this, and it works perfectly:

```
public void Rotate(double _angle)
{
    rotateTransform.Angle = _angle;
}
```

The problem arises when I try and construct a bounding box for this rotated Rectangle. Before this, I tried everything I could find on here, and the only function that gives me accurate results is:

```
GeneralTransform transform = Rectangle.TransformToVisual(Container);
Rect boundingBox = transform.TransformBounds(new Rect(Rectangle.RenderSize));
```

However, I don't always have access to the container to pass to TransformToVisual() and any other permutation of that I've seen on here returns incorrect values. So I decided to construct my own internal bounding box by calculating the 4 corner points myself (I have access to the Left, Top, Width, and Height) of the Rectangle, and then transform those 4 points using the RotateTransform from before:

```
Point upperLeft = new Point(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top);
Point upperRight = new Point(Rectangle.Left + Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Top);
Point lowerLeft = new Point(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top + Rectangle.Height);
Point lowerRight = new Point(Rectangle.Left + Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Top + Rectangle.Height);

upperLeft = rotateTransform.Transform(upperLeft);
upperRight = rotateTransform.Transform(upperRight);
lowerLeft = rotateTransform.Transform(lowerLeft);
lowerRight = rotateTransform.Transform(lowerRight);
```

This works when the Rectangle is not rotated (rotateTransform.Angle == 0), but returns odd values whenever it is rotated. My question is why? I'm still rather new to WPF, and I cannot seem to figure this one out. I've also tried passing local space versions of the 4 corners ({0,0}, {Width,0}, {0,Height}, {Width,Height}) and this returns incorrect values even when the Rectangle is not rotated.

**UPDATE**
I solved my issue, see my answer below.

Comment: First plz tell the desired goal, and then tell your approach. There might be a better way.

Comment: My desired goal is to create a bounding box for my rotated shape, that exactly fits the Shape. I mentioned what I've tried in my question (TransformToVisual().TransformBounds() and RotateTransform.Transform(Point) and I would like to know why the latter returns incorrect data), is there something else specific you need? I can supply some examples if that would help?

Comment: what do u mean by bounding box ? u mean to show a new rectangle outside rotated shape ?

Comment: @AnjumSKhan lookup the term boundingbox rather than asking the OP to explain a term that belongs to this type of problem.
OP, can you elaborate on what you mean with " odd values "? And with "whenever rotating"? Do you mean it happens right away? Or only after a while? Be specific and provide screenshots maybe.

Comment: @Glubus Sure. So my Rectangle is contained within a Canvas that represents the screen, and I offset the Rectangle inside of this Canvas by using the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties of the Rectangle. When I apply the RotateTransform to this Rectangle, and then Transform the 4 points I created in my question, if RotateTransform.Angle doesn't equal 0, then I get odd values, like -176 for the upperLeft.X, which should be the same as before since the Rectangle's anchor is the upperLeft corner. Visually the Rectangle rotates correctly, it's that RotateTransform.Transform() seems incorrect.

Comment: @RichardJones I am wokring on it

Comment: @RichardJones I created boundingrect using two approaches and it rotates exactly as its containing rectangle. But I think you are confusing the BoundingRect with normal outer Rect. Have you tried adorners ? `Adorner` is the standard approach to use in such cases.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan I apologize if my question is unclear, I explained it as best as I could. I am not looking for an Adorner, as I allow the user to rotate and resize my Rectangle using a separate window. I am not having trouble rotating the Rectangle. What I am having trouble with it constructing a bounding box for the Rectangle. WPF provides several ways of doing this, all of which do not work for me, and I am trying to figure out why they don't work for me. I am assuming I am missing a key element, but I don't know what is could be, which is why I tried to explain exactly what I did.

Comment: @RichardJones Create another Rectangle and place it around it and also copy all the transforms. Simple !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what my issue was. The RotateTransform applied to my Rectangle had its CenterX and CenterY properties set to 0, which is the default. Since I was using the RenderTransformOrigin of the Rectangle to rotate the Rectangle, I didn't concern myself with this. However, when transforming a Point using the RotateTransform, these values become important because I assume the RenderTransformOrigin is not taken into consideration in this calculation. So, I solved the issue by assigning the CenterX and CenterY to the left and top of my Rectangle before the Transform, and assigned them back to 0 when I was done. Perhaps it isn't the most elegant solution, but it solved my problem:

```
rotateTransform.CenterX = Rectangle.Left;
rotateTransform.CenterY = Rectangle.Top;

upperLeft = rotateTransform.Transform(upperLeft);
upperRight = rotateTransform.Transform(upperRight);
lowerLeft = rotateTransform.Transform(lowerLeft);
lowerRight = rotateTransform.Transform(lowerRight);

rotateTransform.CenterX = 0;
rotateTransform.CenterY = 0;
```